# Sitecore Commerce Sorting Product by Most Viewed

Tags: sitecore-commerce, xconnect, experience-analytics

I have a requirement in our **Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 update 2** to sort the ***Product List*** by popularity which means sorting by most viewed products on top.

I have tried to get it from **Fact_PageViews** table in **Reporting** database but it was not successful because whenever I accessed ***Product Detail*** page, the wildcard item was tracked into **Fact_PageViews** table instead of **Product** item.

I found Experience Analytics could show ***Most viewed product details*** in its Dashboard. How can I get this information to use for sorting? Is there any way to get it by using XConnect?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Thanks